# Is there a verb that fits in the pattern: quarter, third, halve (divide), [???], double, triple, quadruple. . .?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, numbers

If these were nouns, I would assume "single" fits in between:

> **1/4, 1/3, 1/2, *1*, 2, 3, 4 . . .**
>
> quarter, third, half, *single* or *one*, double, triple, quadruple . . .

Note that each word has a cardinal as part of its etymology: *quarter* evolved from the Latin *quattuor* ("four"), *double* from Latin *duplus* (“twofold”), and so on.

However, in the case of verbs, is there a word to indicate **multiplying (or dividing) by one** that fits into this pattern? The closest I can think of is [*unify*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unify), "cause to become one", but it wouldn't make sense in context:

> She *doubled* the number, i.e. multiplied by two.
> She *unified* the number, i.e. multiplied by one.

The word wouldn't necessarily have to have the *mono-* or *uni-* prefix, but the etymological root ought to contain the cardinal for **one** (i.e. "she *maintained* the number" wouldn't work) *in keeping with the pattern*.

Comment: If they were nouns, I'd say '*whole*' is the proper word for 1.  In the context of profits she '*matched*' her profits.

Comment: @Jim I thought about whether or not "whole", "all", etc. should be the root since that's the baseline; however, I'm looking for a verb to describe the actual operation. When something is "quartered", it is "divided by four". When something is "doubled", it is "multiplied by two". What word would indicate something is "multiplied by one"? I didn't mean to mislead anyone with "profits" as I'm aware of better word choices. It was for the sake of example to see the verb "in action".

Comment: Rather than trying to find a verb to convey what you want, I'd probably restructure the sentence instead.  For example: _In the first quarter, she doubled her profits. In the second quarter, profits remained flat_. Other ways to express that might include profits _held steady_, or profits _stayed even._

Comment: @J.R. Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm not actually trying to express anything with regard to profits. This is purely a question about a pattern of etymological roots, which is why I added the [word-games] tag. I will try to update my question accordingly.

Comment: Interesting question! It's difficult for me to think of a situation where I would multiply anything by one in real life, which is why I think there isn't a nice verb for this. I would use 'stabilize' to indicate I wanted to bring something back to baseline or original state, but I don't think that is your intent.

Comment: It would seem that because multiplying by 1 yeilds no change, then logically nothing has been done, so our grammar has not evolved to include this verb because we see it as a non-action. The closest I can think of is what @Zairja said, but I'd cringe to hear it used as a verb. "Once"

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613786/2085).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I scoured the Internet until the wee hours of the morn and have found [*once*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/once):

> adv. - (mathematics) multiplied by one: indicating that a number is multiplied by one
>
> Etymology: . . .from Old English *ānes* (“of one”), genitive of *ān* (“one”)

This definition was not in every source I looked at, but it was used in this sense in math books of the nineteenth century, if not earlier. The form is usually: "*once* five is five". Unfortunately, a verb form doesn't appear to exist (e.g. "she *onced* seven"), and something like "she took *once* seven" would have to suffice. Someone may still be able to fill in the blank, though.

Comment: The great thing about English is that you can verb almost any word by zero-derivation. “She onced seven” works just as well to me as “once seven is seven” does (that is, not very well at all, but if you are made aware of the background, it kind of works). A Man of Kent’s answer, _single(d)_, is much more intuitive to me and is also from a root meaning ‘one’, though you have to go back a bit further.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of a satisfactory verb for the question's purpose.  There are several nouns corresponding to the unit multiplier, such as *[unit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unit#Noun)*, in sense 2, “The number one”. Note that the more-specialized sense 10, “(algebra) An element of a ring having a multiplicative inverse. (Formerly just the identity element 1R of a ring.)”, would in some rings include just the units 1 and -1, but in others may include numerous other values with magnitudes other than 1.  Term *[unity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unity#Noun)*, in sense 1 is “Oneness; the state or fact of being one undivided entity”, and in sense 4 is “(mathematics) Any element of a set or field that behaves under a given operation as the number 1 behaves under multiplication.”  Term *[identity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/identity#Noun)* in senses 5 and 6 is “(algebra, computing) Any function which maps all elements of its domain to themselves” and “(algebra) An element of an algebraic structure which, when applied to another element under an operation in that structure, yields this, second element.”

For verbs, there is the rather clumsy *[identity mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_mapping)*; one could say “she identity-mapped (or unity-mapped) her investment in (or to) profits”, which ought to mean 100% [ROI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_investment), but whether it would be understood as such, or as gibberish, one hesitates to say.

Comment: I think that term *identity* is the best one, but does not lend itself well to a verb. The OP has been citing division and multiplication *functions*. The site https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function says: "an identity *function*, also called an identity relation or identity map or identity transformation, is a function that always returns the same value that was used as its argument." But agreed, it's clumsy to say "She *identity-mapped* the number, e.g., started and ended with 50."

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly:

> [***identify***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/identify)  a: to cause to be or become identical

could actually work here.

Comment: +1 to both you and jwpat7. This verb does the job of showing multiplication by one, but its etymology stems from Latin *idem* (“the same”) rather than a root meaning "one", "unit" or "single".

Answer (score 2):

I would assume *singled*, as in *singled out*.

What about to divide by 3? Halved, quartered, thirded?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U.I hope you'll take the [tour] to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 1):

How about "Reflected"?

She reflected the number 5 to make 5.  She doubled the number 5 to make 10.

I don't think it's standard usage, but it ought to be!