# Double is to triple as halve is to ...?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Divide by three" is the only way I know to say this but I'm looking for a single word, if one exists.

Comment: *[Is there a verb that fits in the pattern: quarter, third, halve (divide), ???, double, triple, quadruple. . .?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80136/)* seems to imply it should be *third*, but I've never heard that verb usage.

Comment: Double is to triple as halve is to "cut into thirds."

Comment: Double is to triple as halve is to three fourths. Hah! I _rock_ the SATs

Comment: You don't usually hear *third* used by itself like *half*. But I regularly hear *a third* or *one third*. For instance "I'll take a third of that za." That violates the single word restriction though.

Comment: But a half is obviously singular, as it's one or the other half in question. With thirds, you could have one or two thirds, hence having to generally speak about a third or one third.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613786/2085).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The OED defines *third*, verb, as such:

> To divide (anything) into three equal parts; to reduce to one third of the number or bulk.

and it gives an example from 1874:

> Such a course would have halved or thirded the number of our subscribers.

However, as choster pointed out in a comment, this seems to be rare.

I did an [ngrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=halved%2Cthirded&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chalved%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthirded%3B%2Cc0) which shows the relative changes in *halved*, *thirded* over time, and the usage of *halved* has increased while the usage of *thirded* has decreased. Similarly, the usage of [thrice](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=twice%2Cthrice&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwice%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrice%3B%2Cc0) is also decreasing over time. This suggests to me that you should avoid using the word "thirded" despite it being a recognized usage.

Another answer provides the word "trisect". This word doesn't fit precisely in the collection "quartered, X, halved", but rather goes with "bisect, trisect, quadrisect". These words seem to me to be more technical in nature, used for geometry (e.g. [Trisecting the Angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection)) or other mathematical or scientific contexts. Also, trisect can only be used for the sense "to cut into three equal parts" and not in the sense "to reduce to one third the size".

Interestingly [*halved* is more popular than *bisected*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bisected%2C+halved&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbisected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chalved%3B%2Cc0) but [*tristected* is more popular than *thirded*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trisected%2Cthirded&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrisected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthirded%3B%2Cc0).

Tl;dr:

- If you want to fill the "quartered, halved, etc" group, use *thirded*.
- If you want language people actually use, just say "cut into thirds" or "divided into three" or something similar.
- If you need a current, **single** word, *trisected* is probably your best bet but it doesn't really fit the pattern nor satisfy all the meanings.

Comment: I upvoted all three answers I see, but this is the best one. I upvote it harder.

Comment: "What man/ Thirds his own worth?" *Two Noble Kinsmen, I, ii.*

Comment: @DCShannon - Exactly the problem I always get. I want to be able to vote for "this answer is useful", and have a separate vote, one per question, which says "this answer is best". But only the OP gets those. :( No fair!

Comment: thirded makeths me thpbfeel like Daffy Duck

Comment: Interestingly, the *present tense* version of "third" as a verb [has no results at all](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=third_*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cthird_*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthird_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthird_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthird_ADV%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthird_NUM%3B%2Cc0).  I have no idea what to make of this.

Answer (score 26):

*Halve* means [two things](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halve):

> - to divide (something) into two equal parts: to divide (something) into halves
> - to reduce (something) to one half of the original amount or size

For the first, **trisect** is a good option, but in my experience the second meaning is more common, as in *The budget for our project was halved.*

You cannot equally say: **The budget for our project was trisected*, as that sounds as if it was split into three, and shared among three parties.

Your best bet for the second meaning is probably: *The budget for our project was **reduced to a third**.*

(Actually, **trisect** already sounds a bit mathematical and formal; it doesn't sound like something you'd say in casual conversation. **Split in three** is better there.)

Comment: So, would you say that using "trisect" would be [cutting hair in four](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/couper_les_cheveux_en_quatre)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a long-standing English word for dividing into three parts. Also, it looks like *halve* is from a word that originally  meant *divide* without carrying the specific meaning of *divide in two*:

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/half

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/halbaz

I would also note that neither *halve* nor *half* appears to bear any relationship to words for *two* or *three*. By contrast *twice* and *thrice* are words for *two* and *three* with endings that signify use as an adverb.